# Создание приложения на андроид

Tags: android, android-studio

Итак, вопрос глупый, но я не смог найти ответ в интернете или в GPT

В Общем, есть ли возможность создания приложения на андроид, суть которого отображения информации с сайтов не как отображает сайт, а в удобном формате (по аналогии сайт "ВК" - приложение "ВК"). Если да, то куда копать и что использовать для такой разработки (помимо Android Studio)

сайты:

- https://rgsu.net/for-students/timetable/timetable/
- https://sdo.rgsu.net/
- https://portfolio.rgsu.net/

---

Кое-что важное

1. Подразумевается что сначала будет страница входа в аккаунт
2. Не уверен, что у этих сайтов есть хоть какое-то API как у ВК..

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Всё отображаемое на сайтах - суть структурированный текст, получаемый с сервера и отрисованный движком браузера. Вам надо этот структурированный текст в приложении с сервера получить также, как его браузер получает. И отрисовать его как хочется, но уже средствами AndroidSdk.

В первую очередь освойте консоль браузера - там вы сможете посмотреть какие сетевые запросы отправляются браузером для получения инфы для сайта. Там же увидите в каком виде сервер данные отдаёт. Это будет либо JSON (что лучше), либо HTML, что сильно хуже.

Если JSON - парсите его и отображайте как хотите.

Если HTML - также парсите его и сами формируйте данные в удобном вам формате для отображаения на экране.

---

С логином/авторизацией - всё тоже самое - смотрите в консоли браузера как она сделана на сайте. Скорее всего в ответ на сетевой запрос с отправкой логина-паролья придёт кука. Коли так - повторяйте из приложения этот запрос, берите куку из ответа и крепите её в заголовке к последующим запросам.

Comment: Супер, окей, можете посоветовать какую-нибудь литературу или уроки на видеохостингах, которые помогут мне разобраться в этом

Comment: К сожалению по материалам подсказать ничего не могу - сам изучал просто методом тыка во всё подряд)